# title and meta tag decoration (style)

Tags: html, css, title

I want to decorate `<title><p>AAA</p></title>` and `<meta name="decrition" content="AAA">`.

But I included `<p>` and wrote css: `p{color:red;size:1000px}`

However, title is displayed as `<p>AAA</p>`

Do you know how to style these?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here, but you can't add styles to the title tag. The title tag is for the title that the browser tab would be showing by the address bar, not something that's displayed in your page directly. Maybe you're trying to edit the wrong thing.

Comment: OK. Now, I've understood that title tag is not work with css.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with css you cant call the size of something like size: 1000px;

```css
p{
height: 25px;
width: 30px;}
```

This is how you can adjust the size instead.